# Converting to_char to put (Oracle SQL to PROC SQL)

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to convert an Oracle SQL statement to a SAS equivalent.

Here is the line in question in Oracle SQL

```
case when ((to_char(csm.csm_start_time, 'HH24MI')  >= '0700' and 
            to_char(csm.csm_start_time, 'HH24MI') <= '1659')
```

The actual data is in this format: `2010-02-01 08:00:00`

Is there a similar way to grab the 24 hour equivalent time from this date time field in one shot like the Oracle SQL version?

I know that the `to_char` equivalent is `PUT` and the closest format would probably be `hhmm`. I'm not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a datetime field in SAS, you'd just want to use the HOUR function.

```
if hour(csm_start_Time) ge 7 and hour(csm_Start_time) lt 17
```

(or use `in` or `between` depending on the context).